# after clear error log file In open cart again show error

Tags: php, opencart

I am working in open cart Version 2.1.0.1,and my project is complete i am add some custom change in open cart by use it's mvc structure,open cart UI work properly nothing error show in front/admin all module and and code work properly,data insert properly nothing wrong so problem is when i clear error log file in after some page refresh,and again error is showing in error log file,what happen why error log show some error in debugging no error is find.

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\view\theme\default\template\sellerprofile\sellerprofile_form.tpl on line 218
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text_seller_agree in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\view\theme\default\template\sellerprofile\sellerprofile_form.tpl on line 691
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: product_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\view\theme\default\template\sellerproduct\product_form.tpl on line 90



 <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-product" class="form-horizontal">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-general" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_general; ?></a></li>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_data){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-data" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_data; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_links){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-links" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_links; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_attribute){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-attribute" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
         <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_options){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-option" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_option; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_recurring){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-recurring" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_recurring; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_discount){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-discount" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_discount; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_special){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-special" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_special; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_image){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-image" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_image; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_reward_points){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-reward" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_reward; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
        <?php if($config_multiseller_tab_design){ ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-design" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a></li>
         <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-general">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="languagetab">
            <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
            <li><a href="#languagetab<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><img src="admin/view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /> <?php echo $language['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="languagetab<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
              <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!--  <input type="text" name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['name'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />-->

                  <?php if (isset($error_name[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                  <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--New Code Start-->
               <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['name'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-product" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
                </div> <!--End New Code Start-->

              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_description; ?></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <textarea name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_description; ?>" id="input-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-meta-title<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_meta_title; ?></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <!--<input type="text" name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][meta_title]" value="<?php echo isset($product_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $product_description[$language['language_id']]['meta_title'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_meta_title; ?>" id="input-meta-title<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />-->
                    <!--New Code Start-->
                   <input type="text" name="product_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][meta_title]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_meta_title; ?>" id="input-meta-title<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                     <!--End New Code Start-->
                  <?php if (isset($error_meta_title[$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                  <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_meta_title[$language['language_id']]; ?></div>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us the code from these files.

Comment: @kanenas ok, i added this.

Comment: Is this the **product_form.tpl**?

Comment: @kanenas yes, change show in between new code comment

Comment: ```PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: product_id``` means that in your controller (maybe... ```catalog/controller/sellerproduct/product_form.php```) there is no ```$product_id```.